# How do I get a table like this in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx

I want to create a table just like this. How do I go about it? Do I use tables? A combination of tables and tikz maybe?
[image]

Comment: You can use [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) combined with a box around certain numbers.

Comment: [How to create a small cell with borders in the top corner of a cell in the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540550/134144) , [How to create transportation table like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321770/134144), [rectangle in corner of table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101498/134144)  and [How to make tables with a small cell to the right inside another large cell?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583575/134144) are a bout a somewhat similar-looking table. Probably you can make use of the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Observe: no TikZ code whatsoever.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array}      % for "w" column type
\usepackage{calc}       % for "\widthof" macro
\newcommand{\mycell}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{ wr{\widthof{600}} c wr{\widthof{600}} } 
      & & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{#1} \\
      \cline{3-3}
      #2 & &  
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup} 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c*{7}{|r}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Distribution centers} & \\
\hline
sources & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & SUPPLY \\
\hline
1 & \mycell{16}{}   & \mycell{10}{} & \mycell{12}{300} & \mycell{100}{} & \mycell{100}{} & \mycell{100}{} & 300 \\
\hline
2 & \mycell{15}{0}  & \mycell{14}{300} & \mycell{17}{} & & & & 300 \\
\hline
3 & \mycell{0}{600} &     & & & & & 600 \\
\hline
4 & \mycell{100}{}  &     & & & & & 600 \\
\hline
5 & \mycell{100}{}  &     & & & & & 600 \\
\hline
DEMAND              & 600 & 600 & 600 & 200 & 100 & 300 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Final solution table}
\label{tab:fst}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```